# Getting Inividual values from a Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

How can i get each variable into my javascript variable of a Javascript Array into my variable ??

I have this data

```
var Data = [
    {open:100,high:104.06},
    {open:103,high:105.06},
    {open:107,high:106.06},
    {open:109,high:107.06}
];
```

I have a function where i want to return each single value of this 
For example

```
for(var i = 0; i<Data.length; i++)
   var date = Data [i].open;

return date ;
```

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Comment: I am not quite sure what do you want to achive...

Comment: [`_.pluck(Data, "open")`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#pluck)

Answer (score 1):

Function can't return more than one value.

What you can do, is return new array with all the "open" values:

```
function GetDates() {
   var dates = [];
   for(var i = 0; i<Data.length; i++)
      dates.push(Data[i].open);
   return dates;
}
```

This way you can get the value of the second item (103) with such code:

```
var arrDates = GetDates();
alert(arrDates[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var Data = [
    {open:100,high:104.06},
    {open:103,high:105.06},
    {open:107,high:106.06},
    {open:109,high:107.06}
];

function getOpens(Data) {

    var opens = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<Data.length; i++) {
       if ( opens.indexOf( Data[i].open ) == -1 ) {
           opens.push( Data[i].open );
       }
    }

    return opens;
}

var numbers = getOpens( Data ).join(' ');
```

It will returns an array with open properties.

Comment: Thank you very much , i have tried this aproach , but each time it is returning all values , i want to return single value (FOr example each time 100,103,107,109  100,103,107,109 100,103,107,109 100,103,107,109) but i want to return only 100 103 107 109 only once

Comment: var date = Data[n].open;
  return date;                     
How can i supply the value n here from the for loop ??

for(var i = 0; i<Data.length; i++) {
      
    }

Comment: I've edited answer. It will return an array of unique values. That array you can join with space separator with `join(' ')`.